# Изображение с float не двигает точки ненумерованного списка <ul>

Tags: html, css

В админке все показывает, но стоит опубликовать, как точки смещаются, или пропадают.

```css
.block_image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-right: 40px;
  background-color: #888;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="block_image"></div>
  <ul class="block_list">
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
    <li class="block_list-item">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как исправить?

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду список?

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос [mcve]

Comment: И, кстати, по адресу из скриншота у вас все корретно отображается

Answer (score 1):

Поправить, судя по всему, можно только:

1. Разделением списка на два. Первый будет такой же флоатнутый через `float: left`, как и изображение, и будет находиться правее него, а второй будет `float: none` и будет находиться ниже изображения, сразу под ним.
2. Назначить списку стиль `float: left`, который поставит его правее изображения. В этом случае пункты ниже изображения не будут прибиваться влево.
3. Назначить списку `list-style-type: none` и вручную рисовать пульки через `&bull;` или `\u2022`.

*(предыдущий мой ответ был ошибочным)*